# Ad limit placed on Admob account for no reason

Tags: react-native, expo, admob, limit, ads

My app keeps getting a message saying there are "invalid traffic concerns", so the ads are limited and the match rate is less than 2%.
I waited over a month with no changes, then decided to remove the ad units and the message disappeared after a few days. I created new ones and updated my app, but the limit appeared after not even a day (only 1 impression ?!).

What can I do to remove this limit?

(For reference, I have nearly 100K downloads on my app with ~40-50K DAU, and the ad I show is only an AppOpen ad every 3 app opens)

I tried everything that Admob says fixes "Common problems", and everything I found online with no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. I removed all ads units, which caused the invalid traffic warning to disappear from the top bar.

I checked in for 4 - 5 days afterwards and the issue seemed to be resolved.